# RxJS operator waitUntil

Tags: rxjs

```
a: 1---2-3-4--5---6
b: ------T---------

o: ------1234-5---6
```

Using RxJS, is there some operator that can accomplish the diagram above? I have stream A which is a random stream of events, given a stream B which has a single `true` event, can I have an output stream that doesn't emit anything until that `true` event, and then sends everything is had saved up until then and afterwards emits normally?

I thought maybe I could use `buffer()`, but it seems like there is no way to do a one time buffer like this with that operator.

Comment: You can use [delay operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay) for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @ZahiC's solution is correct but personally I'd do it in a single chain using the `multicast` operator.

```
a$.pipe(
  multicast(new Subject(), s => concat(
    s.pipe(
      buffer(b$),
      take(1),
    ),
    s
  )),
)
```

`multicast` will basically spit the stream into two where `concat` will first subscribe to the first one that is buffered until `b$` emits. Then it completes immediately because of `take(1)` and `concat` subscribe to the same steam again but this time unbuffered.

Comment: According to docs, with RxJS 7, `multicast` (and it's derivatives) is now deprecated and will be removed with v8

Answer (score 3):

```js
const { concat, interval, of, from } = rxjs;
const { share, delay, toArray, takeUntil, mergeMap } = rxjs.operators;

const waitUntil = signal$ => source$ => {
  const sharedSource$ = source$.pipe(share());
  return concat(
    sharedSource$.pipe(
      takeUntil(signal$),
      toArray(),
      mergeMap(from)
    ),
    sharedSource$
  );
}

const stopWaiting$ = of('signal').pipe(delay(2000));

const source$ = interval(500).pipe(
    waitUntil(stopWaiting$)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, using TypeScript:

```js
export const queueUntil = <T>(signal$: Observable<any>) => (source$: Observable<T>) => {
    let shouldBuffer = true;

    return source$.pipe(
        bufferWhen(() => shouldBuffer ? signal$.pipe(
            tap(() => shouldBuffer = false),
        ) : source$),
        concatMap(v => v),
    );
};
```

and can be used like this:

```js
a$.pipe(
    queueUntil(b$)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

All existing answers here (as of 2022/1/4) have the potential to skip/eat source notifications emitted on the same frame as the notifier emits (particularly if the source stream feeds new values back into itself). This solution supports this use case:

```ts
function waitUntil<T>(notifier$: Observable<any>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source$: Observable<T>) => {
    const buffer$ = new ReplaySubject<T>();
    let doBuffer = true;
    source$.pipe(takeWhile(() => doBuffer, true)).subscribe(buffer$);
    return notifier$.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(() => {
        doBuffer = false;
        return concat(buffer$, source$);
      }),
    );
  };
}
```